# How to keep text by icon on table (responsive design)

Tags: html, css, text, html-table, responsive

I'm working on a project for my thesis on school but I'm facing some problems. We need to make our website responsive although we've never seen this... It's pretty hard and without making things to complicated I'm trying to make a table responsive. When I smaller the screen size I get this at the moment:
[image: Screenshot]

**My friend proposed to do this, but the icons are below each other than and I think this a bad work around:**

```html
<table align="center"">
  <td>
    <tr> <img href="afspraken.html"  src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon"> </tr>
    </br>
    <tr> <a href="afspraken.html" class="icontext"> Afspraken </a> </tr>
  </td>
  <td>
    <tr>
      <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon">
    </tr>
    <br />
    <tr>
      <a href="afspraken.html" class="icontext"> Situaties </a>
    </tr>
  </td>

</table>
```

**My code is like this atm:**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.container{
  margin: auto;
}


h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}


.title{
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-5deg);
  display: block;
  margin-left:50%;
}











.icon{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  td {
      float: left;
      margin-right:10px;
      width: 45%;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
      clear: left;
  }
  .icon{
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



.icontext{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}



table {
    border-spacing: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}








.contactbtn{
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="display: block;">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Knowledge base</title>
  <href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Titel-->
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" >
       <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
    </span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>


<!--Icoontjes-->
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="afspraken.html"><img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon"></a></td>
    <td><img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon"></td>
    <td><img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon"></td>
    <td><img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="icontext">Afspraken</td>
      <td class="icontext">Situaties</td>
      <td class="icontext">Grenzen</td>
      <td class="icontext">Categoriëen</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--Contact-->

</html>
```

**What makes the table responsive is this part:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  td {
      float: left;
      margin-right:10px;
      width: 45%;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
      clear: left;
  }
  .icon{
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
```

Thanks on advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing first. Tables are not responsive and that is why in today's world, developers do not use tables unless they actually need them. Instead use `<div>`s

What I did here was take off the table and replace them with `<div class="icon-div">` tags.
I then gave the following styles

```
.icon-div {
  display: inline-block; /* This makes the div line up and when it reaches the end of the viewport it will fall under the other */
  padding: 20px; /* Just for looks */
}
```

You can then Style it to center and everything else.

---

I also changed your `<h1>`

```
.title{
  transform: /*translateX(-50%)*/ rotate(-5deg); /* Don't need to translate it when you can center it using margin */
  display: block;
  /*margin-left:50%; Took this out as well */
  margin: 0 auto; /* This is the trick to center things on the screen */
}
```

---

Check the code below:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.container{
  margin: auto;
}


h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}


.title{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}


.icon-div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}


.icon{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  td {
      float: left;
      margin-right:10px;
      width: 45%;
  }
  td:nth-child(3) {
      clear: left;
  }
  .icon{
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



.icontext{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}



table {
    border-spacing: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}








.contactbtn{
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Knowledge base</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Title-->
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" >
       <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
    </span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>


<!--Icoontjes-->
<div>

  <div class="icon-div">
    <a href="afspraken.html">
      <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon">
    </a>
    <span class="icontext">Afspraken</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="icon-div">
    <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon">
    <span class="icontext">Situaties</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="icon-div">
    <img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon">
    <span class="icontext">Grenzen</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="icon-div">
    <img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon">
    <span class="icontext">Categoriëen</span>
  </div>
  
</div>

<!--Contact-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First things first: Thank you so much for helping me. I really appreciate this.
Thanks for sharing this information, it made thinks a lot more clear. Really appreciate it buddy!

Comment: @LucasVerhoest Glad I could help.